# Is there any way to combine these two queries into one?

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database, psql

I am creating a quiz application, and for the homepage I want the user to be able to see quizzes they have played and quizzes written by the administrator and themselves. However, I am struggling to combine these into one query. I have tried joins, but as I'm using a where clause in the second query I have been unable to join them. Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

```
select quiz.title, quiz.quizid 
from quiz 
where id = $1 
or id = 'admin' 
order by quiz.id desc
```

This returns all the values written by a certain id and admin.

```
select distinct quiz.quizid,quiz.title 
from quiz 
    inner join played on quiz.quizid = played.quizid
```

This query returns all the quizzes a user has played

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks to me like you need to LEFT JOIN played rather  than INNER JOIN

Using a left join will mean `played.quizid` will be null for quizzes that have not been played, which means you can use something like `CASE WHEN played.quizid IS NULL then 'not played' ELSE 'played' END as played_or_not` in your select..

Be careful not to use any columns from `played` in a `WHERE` clause, as it will cause the LEFT JOIN to revert to an INNER (you'll be asking the db to compare NULL to something, which is always, ultimately, false)

```
SELECT * 
FROM L LEFT JOIN R ON L.id = R.id
WHERE R.somecolmumn = 'somevalue' --no; it will discard the NULLs the left join introduces
```

Either provision for keeping the nulls or out the restriction in the ON:

```
SELECT * 
FROM L LEFT JOIN R ON L.id = R.id AND R.somecolmumn = 'somevalue' --yes

SELECT * 
FROM L LEFT JOIN R ON L.id = R.id
WHERE 
  (R.somecolmumn = 'somevalue' OR R.somecolumn IS NULL) --yes, but only if somecolumn doesn't naturally contain NULL
```

---

Edit based on commentts:

OK, so the simplest way to solve this would possibly be two part, because a quiz played might be their own, an admins, or some random user's..

```
SELECT quizid FROM quiz WHERE author_userid = $1 OR author_userid = 'ADMIN'
```

gets their own and admins quizzes.

```
SELECT DISTINCT quizid FROM played WHERE player_userid = $1
```

Gets the list of quizzes they played. You can put these together with a UNION:

```
SELECT quizid FROM quiz WHERE author_userid = $1 OR author_userid = 'ADMIN'
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT quizid FROM played WHERE player_userid = $1
```

It's a single column of unique quiz ids. You can join it to quiz again to get details:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
  SELECT quizid FROM quiz WHERE author_userid = $1 OR author_userid = 'ADMIN'
  UNION
  SELECT DISTINCT quizid FROM played WHERE player_userid = $1

) show
INNER JOIN quiz ON quiz.quizid = show.quizid
```

But you *do* lose the "reason why it's there"

If you join all the quizzes together to a left join of the distinct plays:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
  quiz
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT quizid FROM played WHERE played_userid = $1) plyd
  ON quiz.quizid = plyd.quizid
WHERE
  quiz.author_userid IN ('ADMIN', $1) --admin's or their own 
  OR
  plyd.quizid IS NOT NULL             --other ppl's quizzes they played
```

You can work out why a quiz is present by looking at a combination of who authored it and whether plyd.quizid is null or not (null = they haven't played it, not null = they have played it)

Comment: Is there a way to say and R.somecolumn = two values? For example, I want to find both the userid and admin

Comment: The queries in your question do not use the R (right) table - quiz in `quiz LEFT JOIN played` is the L table. You can put the constraints you wanted in the where just like you did. You can also use eg `id IN('1', 'admin')`. Be careful when mixing OR and AND. Always use parentheses to make it really clear to the DB which truths go together. `a AND b OR c` - is it `a AND (b OR c)` or is it `(a AND b) OR c`? they're very different. Always be explicit

Comment: the issue i have is that whenever I run these queries I either get all the quizzes from the table, or I get one in which the user has not played.

Comment: But you haven't said what it is you want.. You've only said what it is you get

Comment: Again i apologise. I want a table that shows all the quizzes that a user and admin have written, and also additional rows which show what quizzes the user has played. I don't want duplicates which is why I have used distinct.

Comment: Then your criteria is `id = 'johnsmith' or id = 'admin' or quizzid is null` no need for distinct unless you make multiple entries in played, one for each time the quizz is played. Note that `played` does not seem to track which user played a quiz, as it links to a quizz id only. If played has an id that tracks the user who played, add it to the ON e.g `quiz LEFT JOIN played ON quiz.quizid = played.quizid AND quiz.useridwhoplayed = $1`

Comment: there are two columns within played for userid and quizid, would this make a difference?   I have tried.   select * from quiz left join played on quiz.id = played.id and quiz.id = 'yTWyoCiMawhDJiECDDkVx6F2Tj23';```

Comment: Erm, do the `id` in quiz and the id in `played` really mean the same thing? If quiz.id is "the id of the user that made the quiz" and played.id is "the id of the user who played the quiz" then you cannot join the tables on id=id, because they mean different things.. unless authors play their own quizzes (whats the point; they know the answers)

Comment: I suggest you name your columns better than "id" - "author_userid" and "player_userid" for example

Comment: Its a quiz flashcard application so users have the opportunity to play their own quizzes. So realistically should I be joining on on quizid?

Comment: It's your db design..  I'm just pointing out what i can guess from the limted info provided. You haven't even confirmed whether what i've guessed about hte two `id` columns is correct. Gettting help on the internet is not an exercise in "see how little information i can give away; people will keep asking for more info if they need it" - you should adopt an approach of "give as much info as you have so the helper can derive answers without having to ask questions". Never forget you're up against thousands of other people who want help and those giving it don't have time to quiz you for hours..

Comment: my columns within my quiz table are id, quizid, categoryid, title and privacy, my tables within played are id and quizid. I was thinking that I would join the two tables on quizid and essentially just look for matches between the two tables where the quizid in quiz matches the quizid in played. I would then also try and add on the rows in which the admin has written quizzes and the user himself has written quizzes. The homeview cant contain any quizzes that user has not played or written apart from admin. i have also made id and quizid in played foreign keys of my client table and quiz.

Comment: also i did not know that foreign keys could have different names so I will change that thank you for the advice.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/LKg6QzjN here is a pastebin of my tables, for better viewing.

Comment: Columns in a key relationship can be named anything; the foreign key definition takes the column name. Personally when i have a column that is e.g. `userid` and it's not obvious what meaning it has to the table i give the column extra words in the name. Like if I was writing a messaging app, i might have a table that has `Subject, Body, Sender_UserId, Recipient_UserId` columns - The `UserId` bit is a clue "you can look this value up in the Users table UserId column" and the "Sender" and "Receiver" bits tell you why the user id is there/what meaning they have. You seem to have `id` which..

Comment: ..seems to be a user id.. But in the quizzes table it's the user who *wrote* the quiz but in the played table it's the user who *played* the quiz. These are not necessarily the same person, assuming I can write a quiz and you can play it.. ? So, name your columns better...

Comment: This will help prevent logical errors such as doing a join like `quiz JOIN played ON quiz.author_userid = played.player_userid` - it's "authors that played their own quizzes" :) Now, to your query of "the home screen shall contain: quizzes written by admin, quizzes written by user, quizzes played by user" - is this last bit redundant? can a user ever get into a quizz written by another user?

Comment: yes there is a search function that allows users to play quizzes written by other users. So they can play quizzes written by themselves, admin and other users of the app.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your help. I’ve taken your advice on board

Answer (score 0):

Try using UNION

```
select quiz.quizid, quiz.title, 1 as query
from quiz 
where id = $1 
or id = 'admin' 


UNION

select distinct quiz.quizid,quiz.title, 2 as query 
from quiz 
    inner join played on quiz.quizid = played.quizid
```

Comment: there is a syntax error around union

Comment: I removed "order by" from the first query. Also, I added numbers as a flag to make a distinction between rows. (as advantage)

Comment: this brings up quizzes that the user has not taken and also duplicate data. I tried making both queries distinct but the result is still the same.